# Power BI: How do I count distinct by another column?

Tags: group-by, count, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

How do I do the following:

[image]

This is the output I want:

[image]

This is the code I have tried. I have also tried to do it with SUMMARIZE and GROUPBY but it doesn't work.

```
count of listings by borough = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Calendar'[listing_id]), FILTER(Listings, Listings[neighbourhood]))
```

Comment: Do you want a calculated table or measure?

Comment: Calculated table I think

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Table 2 = 
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Table'[neighbourhood], "count", COUNTROWS('Table'))
```